# Line break in firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I used `<br/>` in my html code to make a line break.
It worked in explorer but had no influence in firefox.
How do I make a line break which is good for both?

Comment: `<br>` works just fine in Firefox. You'll have to provide more information before anyone can identify why it isn't working.

Comment: <br /> works good in Firefox...Even in Doctype HTML strict

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct HTML is `<br>`. The self-closing tag `<br/>` is used in XHTML.